# How do I configure require js to use local copy of codemirror

Tags: javascript, requirejs, codemirror

This code works when I access codemirror over the web:

```
var modules = ["lib/codemirror"];
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'http://codemirror.net/'   
});
requirejs(modules, function (CodeMirror) { .. etc.
```

However I now wish to use a local codemirror.js file in my Scripts directory but the configuration fails to load codemirror.  Here is my new code which does not work.  I've tried several variations on specifying the baseUrl but no luck.  Thanks for taking a look at this issue.

```
var modules = ["codemirror"];
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: './Scripts',
    paths:  {
          'codemirror', '/codemirror'
    }
});
requirejs(modules, function (CodeMirror) { .. etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a typo to me. This is not something RequireJS can use:

```
paths:  {
      'codemirror', '/codemirror'
}
```

I'd expect you want this:

```
paths:  {
      'codemirror': '/codemirror'
}
```